# Assigning a class to multiple DIVS with different ID's without specifying each

Tags: jquery, css

I just learned that an object can have only one ID, so I'm not sure as to how I should continue with this.

How can I, for example assign a css class to ALL divs that share a certain attribute (cannot be ID as I need that tag for something else) except the DIV that I specify? I could maybe do this by removing this specific ID from the div I don't want to change and then add the class to all those DIVS with that "id"... However I still don't know how I can identify these divs when I need to use the ID tag for something else.
Thank you :)

### The reason why I want this:

I have 5 buttons;
When I click one all 4 other DIVS that contain the other buttons will become disabled except this one DIV with this button. I did not want each button to have a function such as:
Button 1 {
disable1
disable2
disable3
disable 4
} for each...

but rather
Button 1 {
Make itself VARIABLE 2
Disable all VARIABLE 1
}

Hope that clears up everything :)

---

Thanks for your answers everyone, all of them solved what I wanted to know :)

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only can an object (element) have only one id, but also an id can be assigned to only one element. So you cannot give all those divs the same id.

You can use the `class` attribute. This is meant for this purpose since elements *can* have multiple classes and multiple elements are allowed to share the same class or classes.

```
<div id="id1" class="specialDiv"> ... </div>
<div id="id2" class="specialDiv"> ... </div>
```

Then use the class selector (using `.` instead of `#`):

```
$('.specialDiv').hide();
```

Alternatively, you can use a selector that includes all the ids, like this:

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').addClass('specialDiv');
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that this is jQuery ;)

Comment: This is jQuery yes, but since the op added the jQuery tag, I wouldn't think that poses a problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `class` attribute.
The ID has to be unique for each `div`

For example:

```
<div id="myDiv1" class="someClass">
</div>

<div id="myDiv2" class="someClass">
</div>
```

Same class, different ID

Comment: +1 As unclear and complex as the question is, so clear and simple can the answer be.

Comment: @pufAmuf, yes. You can "target" more or less any element by using `class=""`. It surprises me a little that you know about css using `id` but not via `class` which is by far the easier method.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of targeting the div by class :)

Answer (score 1):

just use the feature that one div might have many css classes.
you can check, whether div has class "shared-class" and if so, add another one.
the correct syntax for multiple classes is to separate them with space, for example

```
  <div class="shared anotherClass andAnotherClass">
```

this div has three classes: 
1. shared
2. anotherClass
3. andAnotherClass

you can also apply any css rules to object only if they have all classes, for example:

.shared.anotherClass{background: red;}

will apply to

```
  <div class="shared anotherClass">
```

but will not be applied to

```
  <div class="shared">
```

nor

```
  <div class="anotherClass">
```

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways of doing this. you should learn fundamental jquery mechanism - [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). 
simple example:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='child1'>Child1</div>
  <div id='child2'>Child2</div>
  <div id='child3'>Child3</div>
</div>
...
accessing via JS:
//this will set css attr to child1...child3 divs
$('#container div').css('border-width', '1px');
```